# Online English Rashi (Talmud)

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, internet, rashi, english

Is there an English translation of Rashi's commentary on the Talmud available online?

Comment: I don't even think there's a version in print. It wouldn't be popular because all the translations (Artscroll, etc.) already incorporate Rashi into their translation and footnotes.

Comment: @ba, I'd consider those to be print versions. If there's an online English Talmud _with_ Rashi, that would suffice. I've seen one on a Christian site. I don't know how complete it is, nor how accurate it is, but I would not rely on it.

Comment: I meant to say that there isn't one in print, kal vechomer there isn't one available online for free. Are you saying that you want a translation of the Talmud that incorporates Rashi into the translation and footnotes?

Comment: @ba, Either would do for my purposes. (I was asked a related question and thought I'd pose it this way to the community.)

Comment: Seth asked this question on my behalf (thanks cousin). The background to the question: AFAIK Rashi's commentary on the Talmud has never been translated into English. Yes, modern English translations (Artscroll, Steinsaltz) refer to Rashi in their translation and footnotes -- but that is not really the same thing. And it occurred to me that the internet could *solve* this problem: Imagine a crowdsourced translation project, in which people around the world contribute translations of 1-2 sentences at a time. ...

Comment: ... (You'd need to build in some mechanism for editing and verifying accuracy -- say a rating system.)

Of course such a project would be completely unnecessary if a translation already existed, which (I think) is why Seth posed the question.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss That's the kind of thing done at http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/

Comment: @ba Well, at [the English counterpart](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Wikisource:Translations), since it's an English text.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss, you are correct. I was trying to see if anyone else knew of an existing translation. Sadly, you also seem to be correct that it doesn't exist. But, on a more positive note, welcome to Mi Yodeya!  I hope you stick around. I think you'd enjoy the site.

Comment: There is however a very useful explanation of Rashi in the back of the Mesivta Oz Vehadar Gemaras.

Comment: As others have stated, you may have to use a translation that incorporates Rashi. The Soncino translation is widely available online, and the footnotes often parallel Rashi. The "Point by Point Outline" on dafyomi.co.il also refers to Rashi.

Comment: The public [are working on it](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Berakhot.2a) over at [Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed that on [Mercava](https://www.themercava.com/app/books/metanav/6907) they have translations for Rashi.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/123639/16706

Comment: Yay! I recently noticed this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Rashi on the Talmud has not been translated into English... *yet*.

Comment: Source? |||||||

Comment: It seems apparent to me. The word *apparent* is relative; I can be my own source. When a translation comes out on the Internet, then we can edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no translation of Rashi, but I would suggest using the Text-format Rashi on Shas online at Hebrewbooks.org; they put Shas, Rashi, and Tosafot in a format similar to the Bar Ilan cd, which allows for easy learning, word-by-word.

Comment: How do you know that "there is no translation of Rashi" into English?

Comment: @DoubleAA It seems that it probably would have gotten more publicity if it existed. Of course, it's often said that you can't prove a negative.

Comment: @ba That logic, while formally flawed, would at least potentially be his source. As it is now it is an assertion in a vacuum.

Comment: However, if you look at SethJ's definition which he gave in his [comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17338/online-english-rashi-talmud/18233#comment39333_17338), it appears that there are translations, just not online.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure rashi is included either in parenthesis or footnotes, check their introduction for a guide to formatting
http://halakhah.com/indexrst.html

Comment: I don't see Rashi anywhere in that site.

Comment: @DoubleAA, there's some.