# where can I find Rashi translated into English on Talmud either recorded or printed? Ty

Tags: talmud-gemara

I always find shiurim that translate well the Gemara into English but I have difficulty with Rashi. Where can I find a translation of 
Rashi on Gemara?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17338/16117

Comment: Artscroll (in print) or Sefaria's (online) translations of the gemarra often weave in Rashi's explanation. Artscroll's footnotes are often the entire Rashi translated. But not all of them.

Comment: Doesn't Steinzaltz have an English version that does this?

Answer (score 3):

[The Mercava](https://www.themercava.com/app/) is your best bet for online; most of the Rashi is translated to English, it depends on the masechta. Just click on the line of Rashi and you'll see an interlinear translation at the bottom of the page. It's a great resource; I use it all the time. Also the text of the Gemara is translated too.

Of course, if you're looking for Rashi in print I'd suggest getting an ArtScroll Shas; it's not exactly translated, but the translation weaves in Rashi's commentary and also the footnotes on the bottom more or less bring Rashi's point, as mentioned in the comments to the OP.

Of course there's always doing it the old-fashioned (and much more difficult) way, which is sitting in front of a classic Shas with a Jastrow's dictionary nearby...

Comment: @Jeremy The old fashioned way, besides its inconvenience, is the best way, IMHO. Because although difficult at first, as you do it more and more you become more familiar with the _lashon_ until you can read Shas without translation, which is much more preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best current (and certainly even more so in the near future) resource for English translations of traditional texts can be found on [sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org).
Not all of Rashi has yet been translated, but here is an example from the first daf of Berachot:
https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Berakhot.2a.1?lang=bi