# Gamara Rashi Shiur in English

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi

I am looking for a Shiur that is straightforward Gamara Rashi ONLY on gamara megilla. 
I have tried YU Torah, Shas illuminated and kolhalashon. I have not yet found anything that is English and only rashi. 
I am working on my rashi skill and don’t want other commentaries.

Comment: Are you looking for a shiur that explains the Gemara according to Rashi, or are you looking for a shiur that actually reads through every Rashi?

Comment: Ideally reads both but if you have one that explains like rashi I would start there

Comment: The Mercava app may help , I believe it has some mashectos with translation of Rashi, line by line ,but not sure,check it out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Shiur/Book on Talmud Bavli that has Rashi Inside Translated in English?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/is-there-a-shiur-book-on-talmud-bavli-that-has-rashi-inside-translated-in-englis)

Comment: I would suggest using Partners in Torah or a similar program to find a chavrusa to learn with you in person.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to see a translation for every single word in Rashi check out Mercava (https://www.themercava.com/app/books/metanav/7133) ,I believe the whole masheches megillah  has rashi translated word for word.

Answer (score 1):

[Rabbi Moshe Pessin's](https://www.yutorah.org/rabbi-moshe-pessin/) is just the shiur for you! To quote the person in charge (who contacted TorahDownloads.com which I volunteer for), " I have a unique shiur that I got a talmid chachum to give, nothing else exists like it.
I want to get it out there as much as possible. (We are currently working with him to get them on TorahDownloads). JUST RASHI on the daf so that people can listen or learn the daf however they want and then listen to this 8-12 min shiur. " As of this writing (06/2021) he is up to Yoma, but the shiur he put out yesterday is titled "Yoma 58 - RASHI ONLY", so it seems to fit the bill. Unfortunately, that is a while from Megillah, though I am in touch with the person in charge of managing the shiurim, and am waiting to see if he has shiurim on Megillah.

Answer (score 1):

*(Note: While it doesn't look like he's done Megillah yet, for the sake of the broader question I'll provide this answer.)*

Check out Rabbi Shloime Schwartzberg on [Daf HaChaim](https://dafhachaim.org/). He goes through the gemara straight, but explains all Rashis outside. If you follow the Rashis as he's explaining them, you can often read the Rashi straight through using the precise language of his descriptions.

He also has an intro to each daf and a review of each daf.